# Инициализация std::function в списке инициализации класса методом этого класса.

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток. Есть класс BssManager у которого есть функтор и метод сигнатура которого соответствует сигнатуре этого функтора. Как мне в списке инициализации этого класса проинициализировать функтор этим методом? Ниже представлен код который у меня не компилируется.

```
class BssManager
{
public:
    BssManager();
.....
    void GetAndProcessBssPackage(const uint8_t in_data[], uint16_t in_length, BssPacketType in_type);
.....
private:
.....
    std::function<void(const uint8_t*, uint16_t, BssPacketType)> get_and_process_bss_package_functor_;
.....
};


BssManager::BssManager()
    : number_of_bss_(0)
    .....
    , get_and_process_bss_package_functor_(std::bind(&GetAndProcessBssPackage, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3))
{

};
```

C++14, компилятор GCC, IDE MVS2017.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для получения указателя на метод класса следует указывать его имя в качестве префикса:

```
std::bind(&BssManager::GetAndProcessBssPackage,
```

Comment: Хм. Я так в самом начале делал, не работало. Теперь заработало. Видать где-то опечатался. Спасибо большое за помощь.